# Linq to Objects error in the parsed collection

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I have an issue while trying to parse an Xml to Objects using Linq in a Windows Phone 7 application. The same linq query works in silverlight.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<students>
  <student>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
  </student>
  <student>
    <firstName>Jane</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
  </student>
</students>
```

And all the code that I have is in the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsPhoneApplication2
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("my1.xml");

            var test = from students in doc.Elements("students").Elements("student")
                       select new Student()
                       {
                           FirstName = students.Element("firstName").Value,
                           LastName = students.Element("lastName").Value
                       };

            foreach (var _student in test)
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I get is pretty weird (this is inside the foreach when you quick watch test):
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current = Could not evaluate expression.
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current = 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

In the mean time inside the foreach the _student var has the correct value on each iteration?! Is this error a bug? Or where is it coming from?

... :\

Edit:

Here is a screenshot of where I see the error:
[image]

The students collection turn out to be correct but having that error there frightens me for when i will push out an application to the App Market.

If it helps i am using the emulator to debug.

**EDIT:**
I'm adding this screenshot based on Desnnis's response.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. I just tried it in a new WP7 project and it worked fine. Does the app close or continue without any results?

Comment: I edited the post based on the replies to show more detail. The app works fine I am just thinking that this will trigger some bizarre issues later down the road. I just wanted to see if anybody else get's it running and in the mean time has the same error?!

Comment: That message is more likely to do with the debugger itself than your application. If it runs fine, then it should be okay.

Comment: It's weird that the same code under a Silverlight project works without any issues in the debugger. I presume it's something in connection to the windows phone 7 sdk. Can you confirm that you get the same problem in your debugger under a WP7 project?

Comment: Edited my answer. There is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add a reference to `System.Linq` in the class header. As in:

```
using System.Linq;
```

The problem in your case is that you are setting the breakpoint at the beginning of the `foreach` loop when nothing is selected. Create an action inside the loop and set a breakpoint there. You will see that the values will have a `Student` instance.

Comment: System.Linq is in the project by default from when I created the new Windows Phone 7 application. I updated the code for you to see all the references within the project. I have also added a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I know from the very good begining that student works and it shows the correct properties, but I want to know why I get that error message on test as I have pointed out in my screenshot.

Comment: What I am saying is - set a breakpoint *inside the loop* during the iteration. The foreach condition is hit once, the rest is going on inside the loop.

Comment: Gotcha! That's it! Thanks and sorry for being such a bonehead and not understanding what you were trying to point out. :) I edited the post so someone else could understand easier what you said. Thanks Dennis.